# Plain Java persistence and JavaFX presentation layers: approach for class design?

Tags: java, jdbc, javafx-2, rdbms

Another novice question. I have an RDBMS table called Services that is declared like this:

```
CREATE CACHED TABLE Services ( 
    serv_id      BIGINT        GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 100) PRIMARY KEY,
    enc_id       BIGINT        REFERENCES Encounters ( enc_id ),
    prov_id      INTEGER       REFERENCES Providers ( prov_id ),
    DoS          DOUBLE        DEFAULT 0.0 NOT NULL,
    DoP          DOUBLE        DEFAULT 0.0 NOT NULL,
    DoR          DOUBLE        DEFAULT 0.0 NOT NULL
);
```

When dealing with the persistence of Service objects to this table, I have written a Java class that maps each of the SQL fields into its corresponding Java type field, i.e. the Class Service has the same six fields.  Because I am developing an app which uses this table in a JavaFX application, I have used JavaFX Property fields for each of the types, eg.

```
Class Service {
    LongProperty serv_id = new SimpleLongProperty();
    :
}
```

Here's the issue I am now wondering about...

My RDBMS tables are highly normalized, so I am almost never dealing with the actual database tables at this level.  Before I can present the information in my Services table to the user, I perform this query:

```
SELECT s.serv_id, r.rx_id, p.prov_id, s.*, sr.*, r.*, 
    p.lastName || ', ' || p.firstName AS provName" +
        FROM Services AS s
        INNER JOIN Service_RXs AS sr USING ( serv_id )
        INNER JOIN RXCodes AS r USING ( rx_id )
        INNER JOIN Providers AS p USING ( prov_id )
        WHERE s.enc_id = ?
        ORDER BY s.DoS DESC;
```

This result set has 11 columns or about twice the number of columns in just the Services table.  The information from this result set gets used for a TableView.  Because it is a best practice to have a class that represents the data model for the TableView, it seems to me that I have three choices:

- Choice 1

I can use one class for all purposes, i.e. I can expand the Service class to represent the functionality I need for both my persistence layer (which is JDBC) and the JavaFX GUI API.  I dislike this solution.  It means I'd have to worry about persisting only parts of the object, I'd have to have methods for getting all the denormalized data at the right time, and I'd have to dispense with the appealing notion of thinking about my class as having one role.

- Choice 2

I can write completely separate classes, one for the database table and another for the TableView's data model.  I don't see anything wrong with this, but it also seems that it will impose a burden of a certain amount of duplication.

- Choice 3

I can write an inner class within the Service class, say Service.Extended, that would represent the denormalized form of the corresponding Service object.  At first blush, this sounds like a good solution to me.  It allows me to maintain the separation of purposes between the objects.  The inner class objects would also be able to access the needed fields in the enclosing class thereby avoiding duplication.  I imagine that I could easily create JavaFX data model objects for an ObservableList with a static factory method that would create new Service.Extended objects cleanly in the code.

I can't be the first person to have this same issue.  If I may ask, what are the solutions that others have employed when trying to adapt a normalized data set to GUI presentation layers?  Is this the sort of thing that Hibernate/JPA helps with?  If I stick with JDBC, is the inner class approach a good idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about working back from the UI?  By this I mean:

- Design the UI to do what you need it to do..
- Create a backing class (model) with your JavaFX properties in.
- Write the DAO to store the model's properties in your tables.

By doing this you're writing only the code you exactly need and don't need to worry about abstractions.  The DAO though will reflect the complexity of the database design to the problem you are trying to solve 1:1.

The best and simplest solution is the most straightforward with the least code, least classes, and least 3rd party dependencies.

Also remember to make running database operations in a background thread a key part of your architecture.  JavaFX properties should not be accessed from other threads.  Trying to retrofit this was a real pain for me.